# define the difference between a USAF Leg vs a USAF Sortie

Tags: us-air-force

What is the definition of a Sortie versus a Leg according to the US Air Force?

Comment: I don't have a USAF source so can't post as an answer, but a Sortie is any individual departure on a mission of some sort.   A Leg is a segment of a flight that is part of a larger series of segments.